# How to find branch points

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm solving a set of exercises to understand how to find branch points and branch lines, but I'm having trouble with the more difficult('ish) ones.

What I usually do in more simple exercises, is that first I see where the given function $f(z)$ is not defined, and work with these points, let say $z_0,z_1,...$. Then I consider the argument of $f(z_i)$, and turn around it $2\pi$ to see if there's any change, until now, in all my exercises this had happened. However, I was told by a friend, that one not only you have to turn around these points, but also turn around all of them, I don't understand this nor I see how do you do this.

My struggles started with this function $f(z)=\ln(z-z^2)$, we now that $\ln$ has issues when $z-z^2=0$, i.e., $z(1-z)=0$, if $z_0=0$ or $z_1=1$. Now, how do I show that these two points are branch points? How do I turn *around both*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $\log(z-z^2)$ can be defined by integrating $ \frac{1-2z}{z-z^{2}} $ on the complex plane from $\zeta = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ (where $\log(\zeta-\zeta^{2})=0$).

Notice that $ \frac{1-2z}{z-z^{2}} = \frac{1-2z}{z(1-z)}$ has simple poles at $z=0$ and $z=1$, both with residue $1$.

If we integrate counterclockwise around a closed loop with either the point $z=0$ or the point $z=1$ (but not both) in its interior, the value of $\log(\zeta-\zeta^{2})$ jumps by $2 \pi i $.  This shows that $z=0$ and $z=1$ are branch points of $\log(z-z^{2})$.

Also notice that if we integrate counterclockwise around a closed loop with both the points $z=0$ and $z=1$ in its interior, the value of $\log(\zeta-\zeta^{2})$ jumps by $4 \pi i$.

So that $\log(z-z^{2})$ is well-defined on the complex plane, we need to prevent the above situations from occurring.

One possible option, which coincides with using the principal branch of the logarithm, is to place branch cuts on the half-lines $(-\infty,0]$ and $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: "_You can define $\log(z-z^2)$ by integrating $ \displaystyle\frac{1-2z}{z-z^{2}} $ on the complex plane from $\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ (where $\log(z-z^{2})$ is zero) to $z$._"

I'm sorry I got a little lost with this, can you elaborate more? I see that it's easier to work with $ \displaystyle\frac{1-2z}{z-z^{2}} $, but I don't see how you got that? And what is exactly its realtion with the branch points and lines of $\log(z-z^2)$?.

Comment: $$ \int_{1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2}^{z} \frac{1-2t}{t-t^{2}} \ dt = \log(t-t^{2}) \Big|^{z} _{1/2 + i \sqrt{3}/2} = \log(z-z^{2}) - \log(1) = \log(z-z^{2})$$

Comment: And I'm showing that the argument of $\log(z−z^{2})$ jumps if you circle around either of those two points individually or at the same time. So you need barriers (i.e., a branch cut) to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the standard branch of the logarithm (you define $\ln$ on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$), what you seem to get is two branch lines, not points. You won't only have problems when the argument of $\ln$ is $0$ but when it is negative on the real line. This happens when $z(1-z) \leq 0$, so exactly on the two rays $\{\Re z \leq 0\}$ and $\{\Re z \geq 1\}$ where $\Re z$ means the real part of $z$. Now I don't know your definition of a branch point or branch line in this situation, but I guess these 2 will be branch lines?

Comment: Oops, by $\{\Re z \leq 0\}$ and $\{\Re z \geq 1\}$ I meant points on the real line with these properties!

Comment: What I know about branch points, is that are _those points where there are no changes if we move around them counterclockwise or clockwise_. This is what I have in my notes. It doesn't says much, that's why I'm doing these excercises. I also belive that $\{\Re z \leq 0\}$ and $\{\Re z \geq 1\}$ are the branch lines, maybe because they both start at the points we think are brach points, but still, how do you show $0$ and $1$ are the branch points? Plus I read somewhere that branch lines are "artificial barriers ... wich we agree not to cross", I don't quite understand that